# Limit of some function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-theory

Let a, $\theta$ > 0. Show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-n\theta}\sum_{k: 0 \le k \le na}\frac{(n\theta)^k}{k!}$$
0 if a < $\theta$ and 1 if a > $\theta$

I know that $$\sum_k \frac{(n\theta)^k}{k!} = e^{nk}$$ How can I manipulate this to show the above things

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X_i\overset{iid}{\sim} Poi(\theta)$. Then by Kolmogorov's SLLN
$$\bar{X}\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} \theta$$
Hence trivially $\bar{X}\overset{d}{\rightarrow} \delta_{\theta}$ which is degenerate at $\theta$ having distribution function
    $F(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    1& \text{if } x\geq \theta \\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Observation: $\sum X_i \sim Poi(n\theta)$

Thus the expression inside the $\lim$ is nothing but $P(\sum X_i\leq na)$ which is same as $P(\bar{X}\leq a)\overset{say}{=}F_{\bar{X}}(a)$. By definition of Distri. Conv. we've

$$ F_{\bar{X}}(a)\rightarrow F(a) \; \text{as } n \rightarrow \infty, \forall \text{ continuity points of } F(.)$$

Is $\theta$ a continuity point of $F(.)$?